# Laravel 8 asset() helper function appends url to current url

Tags: laravel-8

asset('asset/script.js')

Expected
https://akbooksnepal.acelogicnepal.com/asset/script.js

But
https://akbooksnepal.acelogicnepal.com/product/akbooksnepal.acelogicnepal.com/asset/script.js

Working well on my machine but not working on cpanel

Comment: try this asset('script.js)  or change your folder name in which script.js is.. like asset('javascript/script.js')

Comment: Already did that . The folder structure is correct but in inner url the asset function appends with page url so i am not getting any images, styles and scripts